# Javascript issue managing variables

Tags: javascript, html, var

Here is what I was attempting with my code:

1. Click an element that has the selection() function.
2. Function sets that element's width.
3. Function selects previously click item (that also has selection() function)
4. Function changes previous element's width

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var lastOne;

function selection(event) {
    event.target.style.width = "50px";

    lastOne.style.width = "10px";
    current = event.target.id;
    lastOne = document.getElementById(current);
}
```

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<img src="images/Star.png" id="pic1" onclick="selection(event)">
<img src="images/Star.png" id="pic2" onclick="selection(event)">
```

Currently, it is editing the width of the element clicked, but does nothing to the previous element.

Comment: If you check the console, I'm pretty sure you'll find an error because on the first execution of the function `lastOne` is undefined and the javascript crashes just after setting your element's width.

Comment: `lastOne` isn't yet assigned to a DOM element when you are trying to set the style property on it.  Switch those lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first time `selection` is called, `lastOne` hasn't been assigned anything and the JavaScript throws an error and will stop working from this point on as `lastOne` will never get assigned to anything.

```
var lastOne;

function selection(event) {
    event.target.style.width = "50px";

    //an error will get thrown on this line the first time the function is executed because lastOne has not been defined
    lastOne.style.width = "10px";
    current = event.target.id;
    lastOne = document.getElementById(current);
}
```

I would fix it by doing this:

```
var lastOne;

function selection(event) {
    if(lastOne) {
      lastOne.style.width = "10px";
    }

    event.target.style.width = "50px";
    current = event.target.id;
    lastOne = document.getElementById(current);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything works fine except the one thing: if the `lastOne` variable doesn't has a value, the error will be occurred, so you have to check, does this variable has any value. In you case `if (lastOne) {//do stuff}` will be enough:

```js
var lastOne;

function selection(event) {
    event.target.style.width = "150px";

    if (lastOne) {
      lastOne.style.width = "50px";
    }
    current = event.target.id;
    lastOne = document.getElementById(current);
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/29/Gold_Star.svg/2000px-Gold_Star.svg.png" id="pic1" onclick="selection(event)">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/29/Gold_Star.svg/2000px-Gold_Star.svg.png" id="pic2" onclick="selection(event)">
```